# Enabling gzip on Google cloud storage (static files)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How do we enable gzip to reduce latency on both mobile and desktop users of static web resources?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can upload Google Cloud Storage objects with a gzip Content Encoding, and they'll be served zipped to clients that send Accept-Encoding: gzip, which most browsers do.

See [Transcoding of gzip-compressed files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding) for more information.

Comment: My question is: How to do a file with a gzip Content Encoding? I think this is usually the job of the server (like Apache) to encode. Here, it's asked to upload an already encoded file.

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question with the specifics of your client, API, and use case.

Comment: A good and simple question about reducing bandwidth required to serve content. The answer is not specific to GCS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172704/is-gzip-automatically-decompressed-by-browser

Comment: Why its for object level, object holds one file right?, how can we hold multiple files on gzip