# Why is NodeJS only showing GZip compression after hard refresh?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a ReactJs no CRA, NodeJs and custom webpack configuration. Lighthouse told me to enable text compression and so I looked into this and since NodeJS is loading React for my view, it only shows in the network that I have Gzip compression enabled when I do `CTRL+SHIFT+R` (hard refresh) however if I just do a `Ctrl+R` (soft refresh it doesn't show that it's gzipped.

Here is a soft refresh screenshot showing that it's not gzipped if I keep doing a soft refresh in the network console, it will not show that it's gzipped.

[image]

However if I do a hard refresh in this screenshot it shows its suddenly gzipped and I don't know why....

[image]

**Here is my NodeJS code that acts as my server.**

```js
const express = require("express");
const compression = require("compression");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = express.Router();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const config = dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, "../config/.env") });

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "/../build/index.html");

const app = express();

var Blog = require("../routes/Blog");
var Schedule = require("../routes/Schedule");
var detailedReport = require("../routes/detailedReport");
var Login = require("../routes/Login");
var Admin = require("../routes/Admin");
var Forms = require("../routes/Forms");
var yelp = require("../routes/Yelp");

// compress the files in build directory
app.use(compression());
app.use(cors());
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

// GET/POST Requests
app.use("/api", Blog);
app.use("/api", Schedule);
app.use("/api", detailedReport);
app.use("/api", Login);
app.use("/api", Admin);
app.use("/api", Forms);
app.use("/api", yelp);

// Serve static files on server
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../build"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server successfully started`);
});
```

**Webpack Configuration:**

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const { EnvironmentPlugin } = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", __dirname + "/src/index.js"],
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: {
            presets: ["react", "env", "stage-0"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      minRatio: 0.8,
      threshold: 10240,
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    }),
    // Disable code splitting as it's creating many duplicate bundle profiles
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production"),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172704/is-gzip-automatically-decompressed-by-browser#:~:text=All%20browser%20based%20requests%20\(e.g.,without%20additional%20effort%20from%20you.)question answers it?

Comment: Kind of, so I think I need to tell my nginx web server to accept gzip compression not just my nodejs code?

Comment: Yes, And i guess it is doing it. It is reading from cache on subsequent reloads. And when you clear cache it is opening new request. Just speculating.